# Formal definition of polynomials in polynomial ring and polynomial evaluation

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, definition

I refer to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring#Definition_(univariate_case)) Wikipedia page about polynomial rings. In the page, the elements of polynomial ring $K[X]$, where K is a field, are defined as usual as "expressions" of the form $ p_0+p_1 X+ p_2 X^2 + \dots + p_m X^m$ for every $m \in \mathbb{N}_0 $ and every $ p_0, p_1, \dots, p_m \in K $.

However, it is stated that another, equivalent definition is preferred since it is easier to make the definition completely rigorous. Here, the elements of $K[X] $ are infinite lists $ \left(p_0, p_1, p_2, \dots \right) $, where $p_0, p_1, p_2, \dots \in K $ and only finitely many of them are nonzero. For example, $\left(p_0, p_1, \dots, p_m, 0, 0, \dots \right) $ corresponds to the expression $ p_0+p_1 X+ p_2 X^2 + \dots + p_m X^m$. I also prefer to use this definition because it does not require for us to use indeterminates (which seem to me to be some symbols whose meaning is unclear).

Now, I suggest this definition:

> Let K be a field. Then $ K[X]$ is the set of infinite row vectors $$ \left(p_0, p_1, p_2, p_3, \dots  \right)$$where $p_0, p_1, p_2, p_3, \dots \in K $ and only finitely many of them are nonzero.

Then it is easy to define the polynomial function corresponding to a polynomial in the polynomial ring $K[X]$.

> A polynomial function corresponding to the polynomial $\left(p_0, p_1, p_2, p_3, \dots\right) \in K[X]$ is the function $P: K \rightarrow K $ given by $$ x \mapsto \left(p_0{,}\ p_1{,}\ p_2{,}\ p_3{,}\ \dots\right)\left(\begin{matrix}
> 1\\
> x\\
> x^2\\
> x^3\\
> \vdots
> \end{matrix}\right).$$

I am happy with this, and everything makes sense. But how about the ring $K[X_1, \dots, X_n ] $? Well, one clearly rigorous way is to define $ K[X_1, X_2]=K[X_1][X_2] $, $ K[X_1, X_2, X_3]=K[X_1, X_2][X_3], \ \dots $ and $K[X_1, \dots, X_n]=K[X_1, \dots, X_{n-1}][X_n] $. But this seems a bit complicated. Using this formal definition, how to write an element in $K[X_1, \dots, X_n] $, for example the element corresponding to the "informal" (in my opinion) expression $ p_0 X_1^2 + p_1 X_1 X_2 + p_2 X_2^2  $ ? Also, how to define formally the corresponding polynomial function/evaluation similarly as I did in the univariate case?

Comment: Define elements $K[X_1,...,X_n]$ as maps $P: \mathbb N^n \rightarrow K$ where only finite number of the map values are non-zero.

Comment: Nice! So then I can define the corresponding polynomial function to be the function $ \tilde{P}: K^n \rightarrow K, \left(x_1{,}\ \dots {,}\ x_n\right)\mapsto \sum _{\alpha _1{,}\ \dots {,}\ \alpha _n\in \mathbb{N}_0}^{ }P\left(\alpha _1{,}\ \dots {,}\ \alpha _n\right)\prod _{i=1}^nx_i^{\alpha _i} , $right?

Comment: Looks right, except that the sum is not required to be finite. I would use the finite set $S \subset \mathbb N^n$  for whose elements $P(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n) \neq 0$, then you can write your sum as $\sum_{(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n) \in S} ...$

Comment: Oh, I think that $ \sum_{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n \in \mathbb{N}_0} $ means that summing over all (infinitely many) combinations of $(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n)$   where each $\alpha_i$ can have any nonnegative integer value. Or maybe I misunderstood what you wrote?

Comment: Polynomials have finite length, i.e. only finite number of $P(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$ is non-zero. So your infinite sum will effectively be finite.